# Stuck on the inverse function

Tags: calculus, analysis, inverse-function

This should be a piece of cake but I really have no idea about how to do it.

I have to calculate $f^{-1}(2)$ where $f(x) = \ln(x) + 2x^5$.

I proved the function is invertible (that is: injective and surjective), but I am blocked about he request of $f^{-1}(2)$.

I cannot find a way to calculate $f^{-1}$. any help? I also have to find the derivative of the inverse function, but in this case I will be fine.

Comment: $f(a)=b$ if and only $f^{-1}(b)=a$, so solve $f(x)=2$ for $x$. Hint:  plug in $1$.

Comment: Try with $x=1$.

Comment: Observe that $f(1)=2,$ so?

Comment: @Randall Ok this was easy, but in general how would I find the correct $x$? Or should I suspect/expect that those exercises will always be that easy...?

Comment: No-ones asking you for a formula for $f^{-1}$.  Sometimes... you don't *solve* but just see it.

Comment: @MartinandFriends Finding an expression for $f^{-1}(x)$ is highly unlikely in general.  By probability, this never happens.

Comment: In general you'd set $y = ln x + 2x^5$ and try to solve.  But there is absolutely no guarentee that is possible algebraically.   It's certainly not here.  (We can probably muck about with the Lambert function but that's not easy.  And unless you have a table of values you answer would be in terms of other functions and not actually a numeric value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing **not** to do here is to try to find $f^{-1}(x)$ in terms of $x$ and then plug in $x=2$.  Instead, note $f^{-1}(2)=b$ if and only if $f(b)=2$, and $b=1$ plainly works.  Sometimes you get lucky.

In general, being able to find a closed-form expression for $f^{-1}(x)$ is rare.

Comment: Sometimes you get lucky.  And sometimes the text authors aren't sadists.

Comment: Completely clear, thank you!!

Comment: @MartinandFriends any time. (It was sort of a cruel problem, but it makes a point.)

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to solve for $f^{-1}(x)$. In fact, doing so looks like it would be yucky. So we only need to solve $f(x)=2$ which will imply $f^{-1}(2)=x$.

IN your comment you asked how to find general $f^{-1}(a)$ for a general $a$. The best way to do this is solve $f(x)=a$ from which it follows that $f^{-1}(a)=x$.

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that there is not guarantee that solving for $f(x) = a$ is at all possible.